Is there a way to customize document names in the Mkdocs left nav menu?
Is there a way to customize the names in the left nav menu on an mkdocs page? There are some that I'd like to display differently within that navigation. Those names come from each document's first H1, but that sometimes creates some redundant things:
For instance:

Product 1
Product 2

Product 2 Installation Instructions


Product 3

The "Product 2 Installation Instructions" name comes from an H1 within that document's md file. I'd like that to just say "Installation Instructions" in the navigation, rather than have the product name repeated.
Thanks!
I've tried changing things in my md file, and looking for solutions for my yml file, but I'm not getting anywhere.
